# Power Automate send direct message to a user that joins Microsoft Teams

Tags: automation, microsoft-teams, chat, microsoft, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

Was trying to create a flow on Microsoft Automate Cloud flow to send a Direct Message to a user that joins Microsoft Teams.

The current steps are:

- When a new team member is added
- Post message in a chat or channel

When configuring the "Post message in a chat or channel", one can select where does one want to post: Channel, Chat with Flow bot, Group chat.

[image]

When one selects "Chat with Flow bot" it will send using the bot. However, I want to send from my specific account.

Is there a built in option (ideally non-premium) for this?

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by combining the *Post message in a chat or channel* action with the *Create a chat* action.

Action 1: "Create a chat"

- Members to add: the new team member's email address.

Action 2: "Post message in a chat or channel"

- Post as: Select "User"
- Post in: Select "Group chat"
- Group chat: Select "Enter custom value" and in the popup select the Conversation id from the *Create a chat* action in the dynamic token picker.

While PowerAutomate says you are posting to a *Group* chat, it will appear as a direct message from your user account, as only one person is in the newly created group chat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).